# Dont understand how a multi-line statement can be parsed without {} curly blocks

Tags: scala

I follow the C family (PHP is a wannabe!) requirement that a statement that spans over multiple lines must be enclosed in curlies.

Scala avoids parse errors in this code from O'Reilly's Programming Scala.

```
def apply(specification: String): Option[Widget] = specification match {
    case ButtonExtractorRE(label)   => new Some(new Button(label))
    case TextFieldExtractorRE(text) => new Some(new TextField(text))
    case _ => None
  }
```

whereas I believe it should look like (the body of the function is enclosed):

```
def apply(specification: String): Option[Widget] = {
    specification match {
            case ButtonExtractorRE(label)   => new Some(new Button(label))
            case TextFieldExtractorRE(text) => new Some(new TextField(text))
            case _ => None
            }
    }
```

---

while Scala can parse it, can a programmer "get it"? I dont. Am I missing some intuitive idea?

Should I rather avoid such a practice, if it leads to practical problems (like poor readability?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the question.  It appears that you're asking why this code sample can be parsed without curly braces, even though the sample *does* have curly braces.

Comment: Updated my question. Didnt know I made a dumb mistake (and what it is)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Scala much more things (including `if`, `match` and `for` with `yield`) return a result as in other languages. And more data structures are immutable, which often leads to transformation chains of `map`, `filter`, `flatMap`, `collect` etc - which also gives just one result. Last but not least Scala has excellent support for tuples, which means that you often get back a tuple as a single result where other languages have to sort out single values.

So in general Scala doesn't deal as much with variables storing intermediate values as other languages do. That means a function is often just an equation f(a) = b, where b might be quite complex, but is still one chain returning a single result. So it is just naturally to adopt that syntax, which makes immediately clear that you are not juggling with intermediate results, but that you follow a more functional style.

It should be mentioned that functional languages (except the "lispy" family with a quite different syntax) have similar conventions. So if you look at Haskell, F# or Erlang, you usually won't see any "blocks" for methods. There are structures like `let`, `case` and (for Haskell) `do` which might look a little bit like blocks, but are expressions as well.

Comment: Yes, reading it as a function f(a) = b made much more sense. And you did perfect justice to that style.

Answer (score 3):

When you say a function = (without the curly braces), it compiles and works fine because it's a single expression.  Your 'match' expression always evaluates to one single value.  And the 'match' is the only thing in your function.  So, really it's only a single expression, even if it spans a few lines.  If your apply function requires multiple expressions and statements, then yes, you do need curly braces.

Answer (score 1):

You have a function that consists only of a single expression. Many languages still require to enclose it in curly braces.

This might be confusing if you are only used to such languages. But after using Scala a little a function definition with a single expression as body starts to look like a function valued 'variable'.

From that point you'll stop missing the curly braces.

So: in almost all cases I'd skip all the braces I don't need. I had not a problem with it in a long time.

Answer (score 1):

> I follow the C family requirement that a statement that spans over multiple lines must be enclosed in curlies.

Wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  bool b = true;
  char c = 'a';
  if (b) switch (c) {
    case 'a': cout << "It's a" << endl; break;
    default : cout << "Not a"  << endl; break;
  }
}
```

Here the true branch of the if statement spans multiple lines, but is not enclosed in braces. In fact, have you ever used if/else if?

```
if (foo) {
  // do foo stuff
else if (bar) {
  // do bar stuff
} else {
  // do non-foo/bar stuff
}
```

Syntactically, there is no special treatment for `else if`. `else` is just a regular key word. This is *syntactically* equivalent to

```
if (foo) {
  // do foo stuff
else {
  if (bar) {
    // do bar stuff
  } else {
    // do non-foo/bar stuff
  }
}
```

Note that brackets are not required to surround the inner if. This is because an if/else statement is a self-contained single expression. The rule is not to put braces around any statement that spans multiple lines. Rather, I think it fair to say that any statements *separated by semicolons* must be grouped with braces. Disclaimer: I am not a C expert. Check the docs if you need to be sure.

Nor am I a Scala expert, but generally I think the Scala mindset is to remove braces whenever possible, subject to good judgement and taste, of course.